# instance data not loaded in template udpateview fields

Tags: django, django-templates

This is my models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """Default user for awesomeinventory."""
    is_organisor = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_agent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_associatetoCompany = models.BooleanField(default=False)



class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Agent(models.Model):
    FUNCTIONS = Choices(
        (1, 'Procurement', _('Procurement')),
        (2, 'Request_User', _('Request')),
        (3, 'Receptionist', _('Receptionist')),
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
       choices=FUNCTIONS,
       default=FUNCTIONS.Request_User,
   )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

Agent form is:

```
FUNCTIONS = Choices(
    (1, 'Procurement', _('Procurement')),
    (2, 'Request_User', _('Request')),
    (3, 'Receptionist', _('Receptionist')),
)

class AgentModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    role = forms.ChoiceField(choices=FUNCTIONS, widget=forms.Select, label='Role')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'email',
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'role',
        )
```

my views.py:

```
class AgentUpdateView(OrganisorAndLoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = "agents/agent_update.html"
    form_class = AgentModelForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("agents:agent_list")

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Agent.objects.all()
```

I'm working on Agent and I've no issue to create an agent, view details of an agent. I'm using crispy form and generic views.

My update view template is:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load tailwind_filters %}

{% block content %}
<form form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <button type="submit" class="w-full text-white bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 px-3 py-2 rounded-md">Submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

In this form all fields stay empty except role. When I look at what is loaded in template, I've Agent instance and User is encapsulated is Agent.

I try to add this in my template :

```
<span class="ml-auto text-gray-900">{{ agent.user.first_name }} {{ agent.user.last_name }}</span>
```

with the span I can see values of agent.user.

It seems that {{ form|crispy }} is unable to dive in Agent to find User instance linked to this agent.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my way to code and used a def instead:

```
def AgentUpdateView(request, pk):
    obj = Agent.objects.filter(pk=pk).first()
    if obj is None:
        return render(request, "404.html", {
            "Instance": pk
        })
    else:
        form = AgentModelForm(instance=obj.user)

        # manage save
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = AgentModelForm(request.POST, instance=obj.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # messages.success(request, 'Agent saved')  # message for inform user of success - See messages in html file
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("agents:agent_list"))

    return render(request, 'agents/agent_update.html', { "agent":obj,
        "form": form})
```